# a Problem with Windows Help Button (EDIT-New problem)

Tags: c#, winforms

a strange behavior happens when install the application and then run the exe file.
first let me explain my steps:

1) i added HelpProvidor and i set HelpNameSpace property to the chm file path.
2) in the form properties i set HelpNavigator on helpProvidor property to : KeywordIndex
   and HelpString on HelpProvidor to Use ASGATech Quran Sound Downloder Help
3) i created an installation pkg. and it runs successfuly.

My problem is when i debug the application and presses on "?" (which is the help button) it displays the chm file.

but when i run the sortcut on the desktop which has been created from the installation package it doesn't.

why is that the HelpNamespce is the same. and the exe which is in the Application folder is that same so why is that.

the exe file is the same and also when i created a new item in start -> program menu the exe file that created runs the chm file but the shortcut doesn't.

i put the chm with the application folder which throws the application folder on:
c:\program Files\Manufacturer\ProductName

and it put the file on this path successfuly so why he can't see it.

EDIT:
i found that the problem is when i uninstall the application it keeps the product folder 
it only removes the icon ans chm and so when u reinstall the application he dont feel the new state (that he has chm file)

now how could i remove the product file from programFiles.

Comment: What kind of installer are you using? An MSI created by Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. i used windows installer. and i found that when i uninstall the program from the controll panel it removes from the registry but it still exists on c:\\programFiles\manifacturare\myApplication , all files are still there althought i set there "Permenente" property to true.

Comment: thnx all i solved the problem by setting up "Permanent" property to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the exe file is the same?

It seems that either the help file is not found by your application or that the current security settings of IE prevent it from being loaded.

Use a tool like [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see where your application is looking for the help file.

If it is not found make sure that it is included within your installer package.

If it is found make sure that it is on the local disc and that the default security settings for your local machine have not been changed within IE.